# Accessing dynamically created variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, lm, rlang, quoting

I created some linear models and stored their parameters in variables. The names of the variables I created in a "dynamic" way.
Now while the creation works, I now do not know how to access for example the paramters afterwards in a "dynamic" way. This example should, although being completely senseless,  show the point:

```
q = c(0.01, 0.02)
for(i in seq_along(q)){
  assign(paste0("lm_", q[[i]]), lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$disp)) 
}

# access the coefficients for each linear model
for(i in seq_along(q)){
  intercept = coef(paste0("lm_", q[[i]]))[[1]] # does not work...
  slope = coef(paste0("lm_", q[[i]]))[[2]] # does not work...
  cat("Write the coefficients to some file...")
}
```

So my question is how I could access the coefficients of the dynamically created linear models.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use a list or vector rather than a series of stand-alone variables?  It seems to me that would make your code simpler and easier to maintain as well as giving you easier access to the information you want.

Comment: That sounds like good idea! Still I would be interested in how to do it. I guess there is some quotion, unquoting ... involved and I wanted to understand in better:)

Comment: For quasiquotation read advance R chapter 14

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment above, here's how I'd reformulate your (agreeably senseless) example above.  I've renamed your `lm_xxxx` variables because, using a list, the equivalent variable name would be `lm_` or similar, which is rather too similar to the `lm` function for my liking.

```
q <- c(0.01, 0.02)
models <- lapply(
            1:length(q),
            function(x) lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$disp)
          )
names(models) <- q

intercepts <- lapply(models, function(x) coef(x)[[1]])
intercepts

slopes <- lapply(models, function(x) coef(x)[[2]])
slopes
```

Giving

```
$`0.01`
[1] 29.59985

$`0.02`
[1] 29.59985
```

for `intercepts` and

```
$`0.01`
[1] -0.04121512

$`0.02`
[1] -0.04121512
```

for `slopes`.

Comment: This is indeed way cleared! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

use `get`.  The following works as intended

```r
q = c(0.01, 0.02)
for(i in seq_along(q)){
  assign(paste0("lm_", q[[i]]), lm(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$disp)) 
}

# access the coefficients for each linear model
for(i in seq_along(q)){
  intercept = coef(get(paste0("lm_", q[[i]])))[[1]] 
  slope = coef(get(paste0("lm_", q[[i]])))[[2]] 
  cat("Write the coefficients to some file...")
}
#> Write the coefficients to some file...Write the coefficients to some file...


#check
intercept
#> [1] 29.59985
slope
#> [1] -0.04121512
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>